# SSRS 2005 outside labels on pie chart

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Does SSRS 2005 allows making outside labels on pie chart ?
For example  http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC36673.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled the words "ssrs 2005 pie chart labels outside" and this article was in the top 5:

[Data Label Placement In SSRS 2005](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9f4367ac-3dd4-43bb-aeef-19f80d8d0e9d/data-label-placement-in-ssrs-2005)

There was also this:

[Reporting Services 2005 How to Display Data Point Labels Outside a Pie Chart](http://www.answermysearches.com/reporting-services-2005-how-to-display-data-point-labels-outside-a-pie-chart/1892/)

So in a word, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: This link is referring to SSRS 2012 , I'm talking about SSRS 2005. Unfortunately tutorials for 2008,2012 are not compatible with 2005.